# Thymeleaf, could not access the parameter

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I try to get value in thymeleaf to pass to delete method, but i can not. Please help.

I have table like this, it is working:

```
<tbody>

<tr th:each="tempCustomer : ${customer}">

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.ipsid}" />

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.docnumber}" />

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.fullname}" />

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.nickname}" />

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.gender}" />

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.placeofbirth}" />

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.fincode}" />

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.status}" />

</tr>

</tbody>
```

But  I don't know how pass tempCustomer.ipsid to the id in the below delete method link:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{delete/id}">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">Delete</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass tempCustomer.id when You press submit in form. To do that You need to add input in form like this one:

```
<tr th:each="tempCustomer : ${customer}">

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.ipsid}" />

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.docnumber}" />

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.fullname}" />

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.nickname}" />

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.gender}" />

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.placeofbirth}" />

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.fincode}" />

<td th:text="${tempCustomer.status}" />
<form th:action="@{delete}" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${tempCustomer.id}" />
<input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
</form>
</td>
</tr>
```

then in controller it will look like this:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private String deleteTempCustomer(@RequestParam String id){
    System.out.println("TempCustomer : "+id);
    service.deleteCustomer(id)//here if You need Long use Long.valueOf(id);
    return "redirect:/display";
}
```

Comment: But if You using thymeleaf i would recommend better way to use delete. <tr th:each="student : ${students}">
            <td th:text="${student.id}"/>
            <td th:text="${student.name}"/>
            <td th:text="${student.address}"/>
            <td >
                <a th:href="@{delete/__${student.id}__}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

Comment: Something like this but with Your own fields. I made just example.